# Linguex Exlabelwidth/sep doesn’t work with Brill font

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, fontspec, linguex

The combination of `linguex.sty` and Brill Roman font via `fontspec.sty` stops examples from aligning properly. When the label gets too wide (e.g., `(108)`), the example text ends up directly after the label instead of standing away from it. This ought to be controlled by `\Exlabelwidth` and `\Exlabelsep`, but tinkering with them does not work as it would with Computer Modern. Is there a straightforward solution (or do I have to do something odd, like put the example label in a widthless box)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, linguex} 
\setmainfont{Brill Roman}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(000)}}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelsep}{(000)}}

\begin{document}

\ex.[(111)] Margin works 

\ex.[(108)] Margin collapses (label too wide)

\end{document}
```

[image: Brill_version]

And here is the same version without Brill/`fontspec`

[image: Computer_Modern_version]

Comment: I haven't got the font but if 8 is wider than 0 you probably want to use 888 not 000 as your target width

Comment: That doesn’t work. I also tried setting the labels to width ```(0000)``` and ```(00000)```.

Comment: The documentation says: “With some non standard fonts the default spacing can be defined only ```\AtBeginDocument``` (for reasons I do not understand), therefore the default values for the above lengths are declared ```\AtBeginDocument```.” As you can see, I tried that, but it also did not work.

Comment: these fonts? https://brill.com/fileasset/downloads_static/static_typefacedownload_typefacepackage.zip

Comment: Yes, those are the ones

Comment: I can confirm your output, the package is doing "strange stuff"  with digit widths:-) I may look later....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `linguex` package does quite a bit of measuring to determine the correct widths of labels, but depending on the particular font properties its default guesses aren't necessarily correct. As you can see from the contrast between the 111 and the 108, Brill has a lot of variation in glyph width. In this case it suffices to make the internal command `\philarge` value slightly bigger (it's set to `4\mindigitwidth`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, linguex} 
\setmainfont{Brill Roman}
\renewcommand\philarge{4.25\mindigitwidth}

\begin{document}

\ex.[(111)] Margin works 

\ex.[(108)] Margin collapses (label now works)

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wouldn't `3\maxdigitwidth` be more appropriate (for proportional digits)?  (Of course, I don't know whether `\maxdigitwidth` is defined.  I usually use "999" as a model in comparable situations, never "111".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is no `\maxdigitwidth` defined.